# How to re-bind content of an Html.Grid using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I just installed the `Grid.mvc` package for my project and used the `Html.Grid` method to draw a basic grid:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("FeedbackGrid").Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(c => c.Id).Titled("Request Number").SetWidth("10%");
    columns.Add(c => c.AspNetUser.FullName).Titled("Requester").Filterable(true).SetWidth("15%");
    columns.Add(c => c.RequestedDate).Titled("Date Requested").SetWidth("15%");
    columns.Add(c => c.Title).Titled("Title").SetWidth("20%");
    columns.Add(c => c.Description).Titled("Description")
        .RenderValueAs(c => c.Description.Substring(0, (c.Description.Length > 50) ? 50: c.Description.Length)
            + ((c.Description.Length > 50) ? "..." : "")).SetWidth("40%");
        }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

Here is my model:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.FeatureRequest>
```

I have put some search capabilities on the screen (things such as an id, name, etc.) with a search button. When the search is clicked, jquery pulls some new data from an action method and returns it to the view (same type as that of the model). This is where I am stuck. I have no idea how to repopulate the grid using the newly retrieved data. Here below is the code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var onSearchClicked = function(){
    var requestId = $('#RequestIdSearch').val();
    var requesterId = $('#RequesterIdSearch').val();
    var title = $('#TitleSearch').val();
    var description = $('#DescriptionSearch').val();

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/GetFeatureRequests",
        data: { "requestId": requestId, "requesterId": requesterId, "title": title,"description": description},
        success: function (rdata) {
            // How to bind the grid to the retrieve rdata here?
            alert('successful');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Failed to retrieve request features!.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the grid placed inside a `PartialView`?

Comment: Thans @SenjutiMahapatra. I think that was my problem. I had the whole code inside the same view. So when I separated the grid and put it into a partialview, I was able to reload the partial view from the returned data. Thanks very much for your help. My head was exploding. Please mark your comment as an answer that I can upvote. Thanks again.

Comment: Posted the detailed answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `HTML.Grid` inside a `Partial View`. Then return the `Partial View` from your controller like this:

```
public PartialViewResult GetFeatureRequests(int requestId, int requesterId, string title, string description)
{
  // Your code here to fill model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.FeatureRequest>
  return PartialView("_PartialViewName", model); // returns view with model
}
```

In `ajax success function`, do this:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/GetFeatureRequests",
    data: { "requestId": requestId, "requesterId": requesterId, "title": title,"description": description},
    success: function (rdata) {
        $('#yourContainerId').html(rdata);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve request features!.');
    }
});
```

In your main view, include the Partial View like

```
<div id="yourContainerId">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewName", Model.FeatureRequestList)
</div>
```